# I need help printing a queue in a header.h file (c++)

Tags: c++, queue

I need help printing a queue in a header.h file.

*for example:
this works just fine:*

***main.cpp***

```
void showq(queue<int> gq)
{
    queue<int> g = gq;
    while (!g.empty()) {
        cout << '\t' << g.front();
        g.pop();
    }
    cout << '\n';
}


int main()
{

   queue<int> gquiz;
   gquiz.push(10);
   gquiz.push(20);
   gquiz.push(30);

   showq(gquiz);



    return 0;
}
```

Output:      10    20    30

*but this does not*

***main.cpp***

```
int main()
{

   queue<int> gquiz;
   gquiz.push(10);
   gquiz.push(20);
   gquiz.push(30);

   showq(gquiz);



    return 0;
}
```

***header.h:***

```
void showq(queue<int> gq)
{
    queue<int> g = gq;
    while (!g.empty()) {
        cout << '\t' << g.front();
        g.pop();
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:
**error: variable or field showq declared void**

Comment: You probably forget to `#include <queue>` into your header file. Also, check to have the `#include "header.h"` in your main.cpp file. You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364209/variable-or-field-declared-void) for more information on the error message you get.

Comment: Do you include the header in `main.cpp`? There's a lot missing that prevents diagnosing the problem. Show all the includes in each file.

Comment: Please show a [mre] and the full compiler output

Comment: yes i did included #include <queue> and my "header.h"

Answer (score 0):

Have you forget to add `#include "header.h"` in `main.cpp`?

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "header.h"
int main()
{

   queue<int> gquiz;
   gquiz.push(10);
   gquiz.push(20);
   gquiz.push(30);

   showq(gquiz);



    return 0;
}
```

By the way, perhaps it's a better way to declare your `showq` function in `header.h`:

```cpp
#include <queue>

void showq(queue<int> gq);
```

And then define it in `header.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "header.h"

void showq(queue<int> gq)
{
    queue<int> g = gq;
    while (!g.empty()) {
        cout << '\t' << g.front();
        g.pop();
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```